# Unable to do operation on running pipeline's log

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube, jenkins-groovy

Running sonar scan to scan the build. Scanning working fine but want to check **Sonar way** profile got used to scan the project, if not then pass the pipeline with warning message.

I thought to get the log of running current build and check **Sonar way** word found then use the condition.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                // Your build steps go here
            }
        }
        stage ('Sonar Scan')
          {
            steps {
              script {
                //Steps to run sonar scan
              }
            }
          }
        stage('Check SonarWay Profile') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Get the console log as a string
                    def consoleLog = currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog()

                    // Regular expression to check for SonarWay profile
                    def sonarWayRegex = /.*Quality profile:\s+Sonar way.*/

                    // Check if the Sonar way profile is found in the console log
                    if (consoleLog =~ sonarWayRegex) {
                        echo 'Project is using Sonar way profile.'
                    } else {
                        logInfo('Project is not using Sonar way profile.')
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Add more stages as needed
    }
}
```

When adding "Check SonarWay Profile" stage, getting authentication error.
**org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method build.RunWrapper getRawBuild**

After getting this error, used the **getRawBuild** instead of **rawBuild** then getting different error.
*RejectedAccessException: no such field found, build.RunWrapper getRawBuild*

Can someone please help me out, how can extract any word from the running build and use it in next stage.

If there's another way to achieve it please let me know.
Note: We don't want to change anything in permission/authentication side.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Jenkins will not allow using methods that are not permitted to use. This security measure is by design. There is no way around it.